# exchange data between 2 usb ports in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, hardware

I have 2 usb devices that are connecting to my computer, I need to take the data input from 1 port and output it to the other port, and vice verse. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 as OS. I tried to use jpnevulator but I can't figure it out.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the output of `lsusb`

Answer (score 0):

I give a detailed overview of these kind of problems in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679480/details-on-usb-no-luck-so-far/17679571#17679571) to a related question.

I would suggest you use [libusbx](http://libusbx.org) to read data from one usb and write that to the other. Basically what happens is that you enumerate all the devices, discover the correct HID descriptors, and plug those into a libusbx interface to read/write. It really is this simple. As far as details, you should be able to look up each of what I just said - they are solid/correct keywords as far as I'm aware. You can also visit the post above for some more resources. For instance, there is at least one solid example on that page at the very bottom. Hopefully this helps get you started!